# ZF2 Inner Join on other timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

**ZF2 Inner Join on other timestamp**

Hello everybody, I would like to detect poitive edges in da Database with Zend Framework 2 (ZF2). 
In mySQL it works with this command:

```
SELECT Ta1.datetime, Ta1.SensorId_47, Ta0.SensorId_47
FROM data_newobjects Ta1
INNER JOIN data_newobjects Ta0
ON Ta1.datetime  = Ta0.datetime + SECOND(10)
WHERE (Ta1.SensorId_47 LIKE "1%" AND Ta0.SensorId_47 LIKE "0%");
```

But how can i join on the next timestamp like here the "+ SECOND(10)" in ZF2?

It works, if I join on the same timestamp in ZF2:

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$sql =new Sql($sm->get('adapter_rohdata'));

$exp_Text = "`Ta_1`.`datetime` AS `summe`";
$select = $sql->select();
$select->columns(array(new Expression($exp_Text))); 
$select->from(array('Ta_1' => 'data_newObjects'));      
$select->join(array('Ta_0' => 'data_newObjects'), 'Ta_1.datetime=Ta_0.datetime', array(), \Zend\Db\Sql\Select::JOIN_INNER);
$select->where->like('Ta_0.SensorId_47', "0%");     
$select->where->like('Ta_1.SensorId_47', "1%");     

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);   
$results = $statement->execute();
```

But I didn't find a solution, for the "next" timestamp, like it worked in mySQL for instance with `"Ta1.datetime  = Ta0.datetime + SECOND(10)"`

Thanks for help... I really searched for help, and tryed a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution [from this post](http://www.zfforum.de/zf2-db/13211-inner-join-auf-anderen-zeitstempel-zur-detektion-von-flanken.html#post83093):

```
$select->join(
    array('Ta_0' => 'data_newObjects'), 
    new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('Ta_1.datetime = Ta_0.datetime + SECOND(10)'),
    array()
);
```